getting aligned pointer inside storage to place object
I have a storage in a form of an array of bytes.
On the stack
// storage on the stack, no requirement on alignment
unsigned char storage[N];

Or on the heap
// storage on the heap, no requirement on alignment
unsigned char *storage = new unsigned char[N*sizeof(T)];

In the spirit of a monotonic_resource_buffer
At some time, I've got a valid pointer p onto some byte of the storage and I'd like to find the next suitably aligned address to place an object of type T (I'm assuming that, in the spirit of a monotonic_resource_buffer, no other objects is living in the buffer "after" p).
// let p a pointer to a byte inside storage, originaly set to storage
// issue storage+N-p is std::ptrdiff_t not std::size_t
// remaining storage should probably be kept up to date manually into a dedicated variable // properly aligned storage to hold M contiguous T objects or nullptr std::align(alignas(T),M,p,storage+N-p);
// or (using a dedicated variable)
std::align(alignas(T),M,p,remaining_space);
// major issue, the required remaining_space cannot be known in advance AFAIU, it may lead to expansive reallocation(s) and copy(ies)

Until recently I thought that you could do without std::align by doing arithmetic on the pointer value representation (after casting, for instance, to std::uintptr_t when its available) in order to check or adjust alignment and to compute space requirements. But, from the standard:

The value representation of pointer types is implementation-defined

Only pointer arithmetic, inside arrays, is defined, in an abstract way. I cannot rely on integer arithmetic on the value returned by a reinterpret_cast<std::uintptr_t>(p) to compute an aligned location and the required buffer size.
But, using std::align rises an issue on the required storage size.
Isn't there a portable and legal way to estimate, in advance, the space requirement for a storage of heterogeneous objects?

I use std::variant<x, y, z> to hold heterogeneous objects of type x, y, or z.  You could have a C-style array of those, std::array of those, or a std::vector of those.

@Eljay: isn't it inefficient in terms of size? You'll be dimensioned on the size of the larger type (let say x is std::bytes and y a very large type, if you want bytes they will be far appart, losing a bit of locality and getting a memory overhead)?

I agree, it can be inefficient in terms of size if the x, y, and z are not close-ish in size.  Alternatively, one could have a double lookup:  a vector of pointers (possibly tagged pointers with a pair<void*, enum_type>, or variant<x*, y*, z*>) into a holding buffer, which the objects can be packed as tightly as alignment allows.  At the expense of having to manage that backing store buffer of objects — like a mini-heap manager, really.
